# Missing Connection Options in Export Wizard : SQLDeveloper

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using SQLDeveloper to connect to a local PostGreSQL database. I've added an external jar to support the ability to connect to this type of db. ( I did this as it is natively supported to oracle ) When doing so, I can now make "connections" to my local database and make queries. ( I've saved the connection as joe_local and can see it under my Connections panel )

[image]

However, when I try to use the export wizard, the connection dropdown is empty and I cannot select anything. ( joe_local is not present, even though I have an active open connection to the db and can make queries )

[image]

Setup details : Win 7, postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41 , Sql Developer Version 4.0.3.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the 'cool' features in Oracle SQL Developer - are ONLY for Oracle Database.

The only reason you can add a postgres driver and make a connection, is in case you need to move some data/objects TO an Oracle Database.

There are MANY poly-db tools out there, where you get lowest common denominator features via JDBC or ODBC - SQL Developer is NOT one of those tools.

It's built for Oracle by Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an alternative, which is right click "table of interest", select export, and have the connection pre-popualted for you. Again, this is not the full export of the db, and is daunting, but it at least helps.

[image]

[image]